# how to read specific lines of list in yaml to python

Tags: python, yaml

I have 2 files, first is `ip_list.yaml` which is

```
globals:
  hosted_zone: "test.com"
  endpoint_prefix: defalt
  ip_v4:
    - 123
    - 234
    - 456
      
  ip_v6:
    - 123
    - 234
    - 345
```

and the other one is `network.py`

```
# Creating IP rules sets
        ip_set_v4 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
            self,
            "IPSetv4",
            addresses=[
                # how do i parse the ip_v4 from ip_list.yaml
            ],
            ip_address_version="IPV4",
            name="ipv4-set",
            scope="CLOUDFRONT",
        )

        ip_set_v6 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
            self,
            "IPSetv6",
            addresses=[
                # how do i parse the ip_v6 from ip_list.yaml
            ],
            ip_address_version="IPV6",
            name="ipv6-set",
            scope="CLOUDFRONT",
        )
```

how do i read only all values under ip_v4 and ip_v6 from  `ip_list.yaml` then respectively put them in `network.py` addresses for both ip_set_v4 and ip_set_v6? (where i put the comment in `network.py`)

Comment: hey can't you use something like pyyaml https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pyyaml` library to parse the **YAML** file and extract the values you need like this-

```
import yaml

# Load the YAML file
with open("ip_list.yaml", "r") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)

# Extract the values for ip_v4 and ip_v6
ip_v4 = data["globals"]["ip_v4"]
ip_v6 = data["globals"]["ip_v6"]

# Use the values in the network.py script
ip_set_v4 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
    self,
    "IPSetv4",
    addresses=ip_v4,     # <-----------------
    ip_address_version="IPV4",
    name="ipv4-set",
    scope="CLOUDFRONT",
)

ip_set_v6 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
    self,
    "IPSetv6",
    addresses=ip_v6,     # <-----------------
    ip_address_version="IPV6",
    name="ipv6-set",
    scope="CLOUDFRONT",
)
```